# How to redirect gmail oauth sign on page to front end?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, gmail

I am using Spring Boot and Angular. Boot is on 8081 and Angular is on 4200.

This is related to [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when access gmail api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974026/no-access-control-allow-origin-when-access-gmail-api)

Now from Postman I do a get on http://localhost:8081/login/gmail and I got the sign on page in response.

[image]

So I am thinking my backend is done now. Now how do I show this page on Angular?

The behavior I want to have is that user click on Gmail Login on Angular, it should show the gmail login page from /login/gmail endpoint, then user login.

Comment: You can directly integrate google sign in with angular also,if you do not want to do any operation with sign.

Comment: yes, I  can do that, but I want to do it in spring. I will try Angular as well. But Spring is preferred..